# Add summary to revision history

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, documentation

In the revision history, you need to click on 'View Edit' of each revision to find what has changed. This can make it difficult to find when a particular change was introduced, or to review all the recent changes to a topic.

One example is https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/559/jdbc/1940/properly-closing-resources-before-java-7 Here multiple people edited an example back and forth until it was eventually deleted completely, but this wasn't obvious unless you checked each edit individually. The edit history is: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/revisions/559 but there's no indication of any conflict.

We can add something like the mediawiki history. This shows a summary of the edit comment and the number of characters changed plus some extra tags.

Or like the question history shows all the comments and shows the changes inline on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

An update to the revision history page that will include more details is being developed.

Comment: Does that include a link to the next and previous revisions, or should I post a new feature request?